# How to use -DATAEXTRACTION in AutoCAD Core Console?

Tags: batch-processing, autocad

I recently discovered `accoreconsole.exe` in the installation folder of AutoCad 2016.

There are loads of command available but when I tried it with `-DATAEXTRACTION`, the command windows crashes and quits...

I would like to get a table data out of a .dwg file (similar to ATTOUT in the integrated console).

PS: I swear that there are ZERO guide on this matter out there.. it's like AutoCAD don't even care about this new feature.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same here, DATAEXTRACTION command is crashing. I believe that's because there is no support for COM API on AutoCAD Console...

There are some documentation, like http://aucache.autodesk.com/au2012/sessionsFiles/3338/3323/handout_3338_CP3338-Handout.pdf and http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/04/getting-started-with-accoreconsole.html

Comment: is there a solution for DATAEXTRACTION?? i can't find any fix or workaround on the internet :(..

Comment: yeah.. I wonder why AutoDesk rolled out Core Console if there is so litle we can do with it for now...

Answer (score 0):

There is a .NET API for that (Autodesk.AutoCAD.DataExtraction namespace). I don't know if it works in core console. There is an article [here](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2008/04/extracting-data.html) showing how to use this API.